# Is there a utility or API to convert SMS shorthand abbreviations to proper sentences?

Tags: java, android, string, text-to-speech

I'm creating an android app that will convert SMS text messages to speak via the TTS api.

This will work well when texts are written in proper English, however when text messages contain smileys and abbreviations, these will be output as garbled worlds from the TTS engine.

Stripping smileys from the text can probably be done with a regex, however is there any API that can detect abbreviations and replace them will the full words?

For example, is there something that would intelligently be able to determine that this :

`hi hw r u 2day?`

into

`Hi, how are you today?`

Comment: Hi, I am in bit trouble finding out some thing like this....Can you please help me out if have some reference.... +1

Answer (score 1):

There is an online service that does it - http://www.lingo2word.com/translate.php

Check what they use - or activate it as a web service from your app.

Another one: http://www.dtxtrapp.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom class to do this easily. Think of using something like a key/pair data structure.

```
r -> are, u -> you, 2day -> today, ur -> your
```